# How does $\Bbb P(A) = \Bbb E(I_A)$ translate in plain English?

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, indicator-function

> $\Bbb P(A) = \Bbb E(I_A)$

If we translate this identity in plain English,

> Probability of an event $A$ is equal to the Expectation of the
>   indicator function $I_A$?

What does it actually mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let's define the indicator function:

$$ 
    \mathbb{I_A}=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1, & x \in A\\
                  0, & x \not \in A\\
                \end{array}
              \right.
  $$

Now, find the expectation:

$$E(\mathbb{I_A}) = 1\times P(X \in A) + 0\times P(X \not \in A) = P(X \in A)$$

Therefore the expected value of the indicator function for an event $A$ is the same as the probability of $A$ happening.